# VS2017 .NetCore project and SDK

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have migrated my VS2015 project developed using .Net Core to VS 2017 and the migration went pretty well.

In my former VS2015 project, I used the global.json file to define which SDK to use for my project as below:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"   
  }
}
```

How does it work now in 2017?
I was not able to retrieve a similar configuration file where I could easily change the SDK version.

Thank you
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2017 carries its own copy of the needed MSBuild "SDK" (!= CLI package) and does not rely on a version of the CLI to be installed.

For CLI commands, the SDK version in `global.json` is still respected and chooses the version of the CLI to run, but you are less likely to need it because the msbuild based CLI is supposed to be backwards-compatible.

That being said, some problems may still arise if you have 2.0.0 daily builds installed and want to use them, VS might not be able to work with that projects - but it can be patched. See https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/231.